# Problems adding OpenAccess Domain model to silverlight app

Tags: telerik, silverlight-5.0, telerik-open-access

this is my first silverlight application, i was trying to work out some databinding using Telerik's ORM.

when i try to add a domain model (or a EF5 data model) i always end up getting the error

```
Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Modeling.11.0.dll' could not be found
```

I tried to add a reference to that assembly but i cant locate it; Im running a windows 7 64 bit machine with Visual studio 11 and silverlight 5.

When i try to open the generated files (a *.rlinq filw which has a *.cs and a *.rlinq.diagram) they dont have any import, using, assembly or some such:

The *cs file only has the string ErrorGeneratingOutput

and the other has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entityDiagramsDiagram dslVersion="2.0.0.0" absoluteBounds="0, 0, 11, 12.375" name="EntityDiagrams1">
  <DomainModelMoniker name="/EntityDiagrams" />
  <nestedChildShapes>
    <classShape Id="c29d1b99-187c-4f74-8450-dfedbee61921" absoluteBounds="0.75, 1.875, 1.5, 2.1473746744791669" fillColor="225, 249, 128, 67" outlineColor="213, 71, 0" textColor="White">
      <DomainClassMoniker name="/EntityDiagrams/UserGroups" />
      <nestedChildShapes>
        <elementListCompartment Id="704aa5b8-74f2-443b-995e-1a0c601f8219" absoluteBounds="0.765, 2.385, 1.4700000000000002, 0.8262939453125" name="AttributesCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="820c2771-dbf2-4f42-a9a7-aec3ba5df7d4" absoluteBounds="0.765, 3.2212939453125, 1.4700000000000002, 0.2493896484375" name="ImplementationsCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="8a50ba0f-43ef-457d-95d5-5764eaa01379" absoluteBounds="0.765, 3.4806835937500002, 1.4700000000000002, 0.44169108072916674" name="NavigationCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
      </nestedChildShapes>
    </classShape>
    <classShape Id="accfcac1-cb17-4e9c-b8c8-4eb0deca766d" absoluteBounds="3.75, 0.75, 1.5, 2.3396761067708329" fillColor="225, 249, 128, 67" outlineColor="213, 71, 0" textColor="White">
      <DomainClassMoniker name="/EntityDiagrams/UserAttendants" />
      <nestedChildShapes>
        <elementListCompartment Id="dcda1f6d-1d49-4789-8461-73ba0b3050f6" absoluteBounds="3.765, 1.2599999999999998, 1.4700000000000002, 0.8262939453125" name="AttributesCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="7b8da440-ed63-406c-a2ec-93777658fe4b" absoluteBounds="3.765, 2.0962939453124996, 1.4700000000000002, 0.2493896484375" name="ImplementationsCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="ffbf24f1-93ff-481c-aa7e-b0a5c7c83c1d" absoluteBounds="3.765, 2.3556835937500002, 1.4700000000000002, 0.63399251302083326" name="NavigationCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
      </nestedChildShapes>
    </classShape>
    <classShape Id="55e0a6e0-5c20-4ba2-9a31-26e8d5a08f04" absoluteBounds="6, 9.375, 1.5, 2.7242789713541669" fillColor="225, 249, 128, 67" outlineColor="213, 71, 0" textColor="White">
      <DomainClassMoniker name="/EntityDiagrams/Users" />
      <nestedChildShapes>
        <elementListCompartment Id="51edae1f-5776-4916-9512-7de25f9e2cdd" absoluteBounds="6.015, 9.885, 1.4700000000000002, 1.4031982421875" name="AttributesCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="433da401-adc9-4ad6-95cb-e00f2c40f731" absoluteBounds="6.015, 11.2981982421875, 1.4700000000000002, 0.2493896484375" name="ImplementationsCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="8c906d26-5a0d-4e4e-b81e-76a7eb878344" absoluteBounds="6.015, 11.557587890625, 1.4700000000000002, 0.44169108072916652" name="NavigationCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
      </nestedChildShapes>
    </classShape>
    <classShape Id="f6fa927f-8a05-4130-bb21-320d987aa5ae" absoluteBounds="6, 3.5, 1.5, 4.8395947265625" fillColor="225, 249, 128, 67" outlineColor="213, 71, 0" textColor="White">
      <DomainClassMoniker name="/EntityDiagrams/TeamEvents" />
      <nestedChildShapes>
        <elementListCompartment Id="257a2039-b72c-479d-a831-77f2e9d97414" absoluteBounds="6.0150000000000006, 4.01, 1.4700000000000002, 2.5570068359375" name="AttributesCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="8b17a7ab-af5d-462a-b3fa-e0f9282c867e" absoluteBounds="6.0150000000000006, 6.5770068359375, 1.4700000000000002, 0.2493896484375" name="ImplementationsCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="ea5fe5b2-a5f7-495f-812d-674baa6fc7f9" absoluteBounds="6.0150000000000006, 6.8363964843749994, 1.4700000000000002, 1.4031982421875" name="NavigationCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
      </nestedChildShapes>
    </classShape>
    <classShape Id="293c8000-fa45-46fe-ac76-ac95e5322451" absoluteBounds="0.75, 4.75, 1.5, 2.3396761067708329" fillColor="225, 249, 128, 67" outlineColor="213, 71, 0" textColor="White">
      <DomainClassMoniker name="/EntityDiagrams/GroupAttendants" />
      <nestedChildShapes>
        <elementListCompartment Id="46cf471d-673c-4e91-a602-465e8565aa91" absoluteBounds="0.76500000000000012, 5.26, 1.4700000000000002, 0.8262939453125" name="AttributesCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="bf0582ab-1dcd-4335-9e92-e62b04cab919" absoluteBounds="0.76500000000000012, 6.0962939453125, 1.4700000000000002, 0.2493896484375" name="ImplementationsCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="a746ad03-204c-4914-a825-06c82d380c9c" absoluteBounds="0.76500000000000012, 6.35568359375, 1.4700000000000002, 0.63399251302083326" name="NavigationCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
      </nestedChildShapes>
    </classShape>
    <classShape Id="d354c37c-69e7-4815-89b4-ce5a8228dbc3" absoluteBounds="3, 4.75, 1.5, 2.3396761067708329" fillColor="225, 249, 128, 67" outlineColor="213, 71, 0" textColor="White">
      <DomainClassMoniker name="/EntityDiagrams/Groups" />
      <nestedChildShapes>
        <elementListCompartment Id="c5691c86-3585-43e0-af96-29dd5ca34369" absoluteBounds="3.0149999999999997, 5.26, 1.4700000000000002, 0.8262939453125" name="AttributesCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="3833477d-ff2b-4e1d-86dc-48a461b9611c" absoluteBounds="3.0149999999999997, 6.0962939453125, 1.4700000000000002, 0.2493896484375" name="ImplementationsCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="814e3238-3cc6-4e53-9b66-93017c87f2a7" absoluteBounds="3.0149999999999997, 6.35568359375, 1.4700000000000002, 0.63399251302083326" name="NavigationCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
      </nestedChildShapes>
    </classShape>
    <classShape Id="1fa0ffc8-851d-414b-8c9c-23953349b73c" absoluteBounds="8.25, 3.5, 1.5, 2.1473746744791669" fillColor="225, 249, 128, 67" outlineColor="213, 71, 0" textColor="White">
      <DomainClassMoniker name="/EntityDiagrams/EventTypes" />
      <nestedChildShapes>
        <elementListCompartment Id="ce6f6ffa-b9e2-41d3-b20e-8f7e84b674b8" absoluteBounds="8.265, 4.01, 1.4700000000000002, 0.8262939453125" name="AttributesCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="52c2feb7-7c6f-4526-b1b6-5fc03a3fcd48" absoluteBounds="8.265, 4.8462939453125, 1.4700000000000002, 0.2493896484375" name="ImplementationsCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="652a57eb-ea5f-4fc8-b24d-3325df489c32" absoluteBounds="8.265, 5.10568359375, 1.4700000000000002, 0.44169108072916674" name="NavigationCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
      </nestedChildShapes>
    </classShape>
    <classShape Id="9dc6ebbd-b634-4c22-b521-32ddf694dfe0" absoluteBounds="8.25, 6.375, 1.5, 1.9550732421875" fillColor="225, 249, 128, 67" outlineColor="213, 71, 0" textColor="White">
      <DomainClassMoniker name="/EntityDiagrams/EventLocations" />
      <nestedChildShapes>
        <elementListCompartment Id="29d5627b-5e61-4e38-9d93-d46e7db93ce9" absoluteBounds="8.265, 6.885, 1.4700000000000002, 0.63399251302083326" name="AttributesCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="b3af0ed9-1faa-40a7-988c-493f44f16636" absoluteBounds="8.265, 7.5289925130208335, 1.4700000000000002, 0.2493896484375" name="ImplementationsCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
        <elementListCompartment Id="3110f146-8957-4587-8ee2-d2a7fc2e62d9" absoluteBounds="8.265, 7.7883821614583333, 1.4700000000000002, 0.44169108072916652" name="NavigationCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
      </nestedChildShapes>
    </classShape>
    <associationConnector edgePoints="[(2.25 : 3.587275390625); (3.34375 : 3.587275390625); (3.34375 : 4.75)]" fixedFrom="Algorithm" fixedTo="Algorithm">
      <AssociationMoniker Id="6744534d-057c-43fa-ab27-e85960bb25de" />
      <relativeChildShapes />
      <nodes>
        <classShapeMoniker Id="c29d1b99-187c-4f74-8450-dfedbee61921" />
        <classShapeMoniker Id="d354c37c-69e7-4815-89b4-ce5a8228dbc3" />
      </nodes>
    </associationConnector>
    <associationConnector edgePoints="[(5.25 : 1.91983805338542); (6.75 : 1.91983805338542); (6.75 : 3.5)]" fixedFrom="Algorithm" fixedTo="Algorithm">
      <AssociationMoniker Id="37b107df-2f1f-4a81-a2f4-6617a15cce0a" />
      <relativeChildShapes />
      <nodes>
        <classShapeMoniker Id="accfcac1-cb17-4e9c-b8c8-4eb0deca766d" />
        <classShapeMoniker Id="f6fa927f-8a05-4130-bb21-320d987aa5ae" />
      </nodes>
    </associationConnector>
    <associationConnector edgePoints="[(4.90625 : 3.08967610677083); (4.90625 : 10.7371394856771); (6 : 10.7371394856771)]" fixedFrom="Algorithm" fixedTo="Algorithm">
      <AssociationMoniker Id="c6256d1c-6cb2-4a57-873b-4001184ff6a2" />
      <relativeChildShapes />
      <nodes>
        <classShapeMoniker Id="accfcac1-cb17-4e9c-b8c8-4eb0deca766d" />
        <classShapeMoniker Id="55e0a6e0-5c20-4ba2-9a31-26e8d5a08f04" />
      </nodes>
    </associationConnector>
    <associationConnector edgePoints="[(7.5 : 7.35253662109375); (8.25 : 7.35253662109375)]" fixedFrom="Algorithm" fixedTo="Algorithm">
      <AssociationMoniker Id="93f4858e-6685-4f69-9005-9a8ae86c6ad7" />
      <relativeChildShapes />
      <nodes>
        <classShapeMoniker Id="f6fa927f-8a05-4130-bb21-320d987aa5ae" />
        <classShapeMoniker Id="9dc6ebbd-b634-4c22-b521-32ddf694dfe0" />
      </nodes>
    </associationConnector>
    <associationConnector edgePoints="[(7.5 : 4.57368733723958); (8.25 : 4.57368733723958)]" fixedFrom="Algorithm" fixedTo="Algorithm">
      <AssociationMoniker Id="94a809bd-0d55-4d97-bb0b-4a1db01d67c8" />
      <relativeChildShapes />
      <nodes>
        <classShapeMoniker Id="f6fa927f-8a05-4130-bb21-320d987aa5ae" />
        <classShapeMoniker Id="1fa0ffc8-851d-414b-8c9c-23953349b73c" />
      </nodes>
    </associationConnector>
    <associationConnector edgePoints="[(6.53192307692308 : 8.3395947265625); (6.53192307692308 : 8.5895947265625); (6.97846153846154 : 8.5895947265625); (6.97846153846154 : 8.3395947265625)]" fixedFrom="NotFixed" fixedTo="NotFixed">
      <AssociationMoniker Id="4bd6231c-14e5-4782-8826-d318a28b87e9" />
      <relativeChildShapes />
      <nodes>
        <classShapeMoniker Id="f6fa927f-8a05-4130-bb21-320d987aa5ae" />
        <classShapeMoniker Id="f6fa927f-8a05-4130-bb21-320d987aa5ae" />
      </nodes>
    </associationConnector>
    <associationConnector edgePoints="[(2.25 : 5.91983805338542); (3 : 5.91983805338542)]" fixedFrom="Algorithm" fixedTo="Algorithm">
      <AssociationMoniker Id="909045cd-67e3-4d3c-8a28-365a92f28f61" />
      <relativeChildShapes />
      <nodes>
        <classShapeMoniker Id="293c8000-fa45-46fe-ac76-ac95e5322451" />
        <classShapeMoniker Id="d354c37c-69e7-4815-89b4-ce5a8228dbc3" />
      </nodes>
    </associationConnector>
    <associationConnector edgePoints="[(1.5 : 7.08967610677083); (1.5 : 7.71463591666667); (4.82291666666667 : 7.71463591666666 : JumpStart); (4.98958333333333 : 7.71463591666667 : JumpEnd); (6 : 7.71463591666667)]" fixedFrom="Algorithm" fixedTo="Algorithm">
      <AssociationMoniker Id="af22af49-aa92-4f26-8bcd-ee099bc70e25" />
      <relativeChildShapes />
      <nodes>
        <classShapeMoniker Id="293c8000-fa45-46fe-ac76-ac95e5322451" />
        <classShapeMoniker Id="f6fa927f-8a05-4130-bb21-320d987aa5ae" />
      </nodes>
    </associationConnector>
  </nestedChildShapes>
</entityDiagramsDiagram>
```

what do i do?

ive enabled RIA services when creating the solution

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a domain model in a Silverlight application. What you could do is to create a separate class library, which contains your [model](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/quickstart-silverlight-three-data-domain-model.html).

Comment: oh, im doing it on the .web app, not on the silverlight one. i was going to add a service do access the data on the SL side. Does that make sense?

Comment: It seems to be an issue related to resolving the assembly. You could try specifying the full path to your assembly, containing the model in the assembly directive:
<#@ assembly name="Path_To_Assembly" #>

Comment: In which file should i add this directive?

Comment: If you are using the Telerik.OpenAccess.DTO template, you should verify the path to the OpenAccess CodeGeneration assembly. Change it accordingly, if it is not correct.